# Identification of a short story about a girl who loses a protective talisman (A handkerchief with three spots of her mother's blood on it)

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to identify a short story or possibly a fairytale contained in a book of short stories, about a girl who went on a long journey and was given several items that she was supposed to take with her.

I can't remember most of the details, but one of these items was a handkerchief with three spots of her mother's blood on it that was supposed to act as a talisman to protect her.

Early on in the story she accidentally drops the handkerchief in a stream and is then tricked into becoming someone's servant (or possibly their wife), and she is coerced into making a vow that she will never speak a word to another living thing.

Someone figures out that she is being held against her will and gets her to shout her story into a large stove (which isn't a living thing), the person listens at the other end of the stove pipe and finds out the truth and then frees her.

I think that it's possible that she as a princess on her way to an arranged marriage, and that she loses her dress and dowry and is mistaken for a peasant girl, and is forced to be a servant in the castle of the prince that she was to marry. Though I may be mixing up this last part.

The original may have been in German.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is the Grimms' [The Goose-Girl](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Edash/grimm089.html), at least as translated by Margaret Hunt.  The princess is sent to marry a prince who lives far away and is given a talisman to keep her safe on the journey:

> When the hour of departure had come, the old mother went into her bedroom, took a small knife and cut her fingers with it until they bled. Then she held out a small white cloth and let three drops of blood fall into it. She gave them to her daughter, saying, "Take good care of these. They will be of service to you on your way."

Her chambermaid convinces her to drink directly from a stream, losing the talisman, whereby the chambermaid takes her place:

> As she was thus drinking, leaning over the stream, the cloth with the three drops of blood fell from her bosom and floated away with the water, without her taking notice of it, so great were her concerns. [...]
>
> Then with many harsh words the chambermaid ordered the princess to take off her own royal clothing and put on the chambermaid's shabby clothes. And in the end the princess had to swear under the open heaven that she would not say one word of this to anyone at the royal court. If she had not taken this oath, she would have been killed on the spot.

Later in the story she tells her tale to a stove and is overheard by the king:

> when the goose-girl came home in the evening, he called her aside, and asked why she did all these things.
>
> "I am not allowed to tell you, nor can I reveal my sorrows to any human being, for I have sworn under the open heaven not to do so, and if I had not so sworn, I would have been killed."
>
> He urged her and left her no peace, but he could get nothing from her. Finally he said, "If you will not tell me anything, then tell your sorrows to the iron stove there," and he went away.
>
> So she crept into the iron stove, and began to cry sorrowfully, pouring out her whole heart. She said, "Here I sit, abandoned by the whole world, although I am the daughter of a king. A false chambermaid forced me to take off my royal clothes, and she has taken my place with my bridegroom. Now I have to do common work as a goose-girl. If my mother this, her heart would break in two."
>
> The old king was standing outside listening by the stovepipe, and he heard what she said. Then he came back inside, and asked her to come out of the stove. Then they dressed her in royal clothes, and it was marvelous how beautiful she was.

Comment: Bingo, I remember the part about the chamber maid now. This is definitely it.

Comment: An interesting typo. That should be "*If my mother **knew of this**, her heart would break in two*"